# Jigsaw Puzzle using cocos2d - iOS

Tags: ios6, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5

I am new to iOS game development, I just completed a tutorial how to make Puzzle by getting an image and move the tiles on touch event. Such a nice and clearly understandable tutorial :) , nice work.

[This is the tutorial](http://www.iphonegametutorials.com/2010/09/23/cocos2d-game-tutorial-building-a-slide-image-game/)

Now i need some help, guidelines, tutorials or some sort of Sample code of Jigsaw Puzzle using cocos2d on iOS.
Please could you guys help me out ?

Thanks in Advance, your cooperation would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Ahsan. There's a whole bunch of material out there which you can draw from for something like this. A simple Google search turns up quite a few examples and sample code / guide links. Check em out.

Comment: i already did searching a lot but i found multiple ways to achieve that goal, but as i am beginner so its quite difficult for me to Implement those. thats why i am asking about some sample code or some Logic to make jigsaw puzzle using cocos2d.

Comment: Looking for this as well. Have you found it Ahsan? Thanks!